# Flash messages only show after redirecting twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

flash[:errors] does not show after redirect_to in create method. But if I send another invalid form it shows up on the second and all following redirects. The same goes for flash[:success] when there are no errors.

I've tried using flash.keep in both this and the route I am redirecting to, and the views work since the messages do appear after multiple redirects. I'm wondering if it is because the redirects are to routes that render too?

```
In Controller:

def create
    user = User.create(user_params)
    if user.errors.any?
        flash[:errors] = user.errors.full_messages
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
        flash[:success] = "USER SUCCESSFULLY CREATED"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

In Views:

<% if flash[:errors] %>
    <% flash[:errors].each do |error| %>
        <p style="color:red;"><%= error %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

AND:

<% if flash[:success] %>
    <p style="color: red;"><%= flash[:success] %></p>
<% end %>
```

No flash messages are shown after the first redirect. After  or more redirects, the flash messages are shown

Comment: Maybe try using flash directly in the redirect e.g. `redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, flash: {errors: user.errors.full_messages})`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, it still waits until second time page is redirected to show the flash messages